# laravel5 and GoDaddy Exception when trying to send mail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

as the title says, when I'm trying to send a mail with Laravel 5 and with a shared host in GoDaddy I get the following error.

```
    Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 265:
    Connection could not be established with host >localhost [php_network_getaddresses: 
    getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known #0]
```

This is the configuration that I'm using:

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'localhost',
'port' => 587,
'from' => array('address' => 'mail@domain.com', 'name' => 'name'),
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => 'cpanel user name',
'password' => 'cpanel password',
'sendmail' => '/usr/lib/sendmail -t',
'pretend' => false,
```

As the support guy from GoDaddy told me, I use the host  as "localhost" instead my domain name but still getting the exception.

Can anyone give me a hand with the correct configuration please?

Comment: Have you tried entering the email address as username and email address password for password - instead of cpanel  credentials?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue when I was using Godaddy web hosting and solved this by editing my .env file as,

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=XXXX.XXXX.in
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=dexxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXX
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Where MAIL_HOST is your domain name from Godaddy, MAIL_USERNAME is your user name from Godaddy and MAIL_PASSWORD is your password from Godaddy.

I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Using Laravel 5.6 on goDaddy, the settings that worked with me.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=localhost   
MAIL_PORT=587 
MAIL_USERNAME=your user name
MAIL_PASSWORD=your password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for Laravel 7 and up, use the following:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```