# Mail configuration in Laravel for Godaddy webmail

Tags: php, laravel, email, web-hosting

I am trying to send email from my Godaddy Webmail.
Here is the configuration of .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp    
MAIL_HOST=dedrelay.secureserver.net    
MAIL_PORT=465    
MAIL_USERNAME=my_webmail_username    
MAIL_PASSWORD='my_web_mail_pass'    
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

But in log file it shows error

> local.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host
>   dedrelay.secureserver.net

I understand that there is a problem in 'MAIL_HOST'.
But how can I get the correct 'MAIL_HOST' of my Godaddy webmail ?

Comment: These articles might point you in the correct direction: [Error while sending email on GoDaddy Server: Laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423189/error-while-sending-email-on-godaddy-server-laravel-5-1); [Email with laravel SMTP of Godaddy account fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509527/email-with-laravel-smtp-of-godaddy-account-fails); [laravel5 and GoDaddy Exception when trying to send mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491254/laravel5-and-godaddy-exception-when-trying-to-send-mail).

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about managing your servers can be asked on [sf]. In the future, please ask questions similar to this one there.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution.

Go to 'Email Accounts'(Search Email Account in search bar) from your Godaddy cPanel. In 'Email Accounts' page goto 'Email Account' tab and click to 'Access Webmail'.

At the bottom of this 'Access Webmail' page you will find 'Outgoing Server' portion under 'Mail Client Manual Settings' section. This 'Outgoing Server' is the desired 'MAIL_HOST'.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [smtpout.secureserver.net](http://smtpout.secureserver.net) as the `MAIL_HOST` instead, suggested by [GoDaddy](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/mail-server-addresses-and-ports-for-business-email-24071)

If the above doesn't work, the following [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841834/phpmailer-godaddy-server-smtp-connection-refused) may help.

Comment: @steadweb...no it's not working brother...still get the same error " local.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host smtpout.secureserver.net "

Comment: after apply 'localhost' in 'HOST' part I got the error 'Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "info@ezmoverandrental.com" using 2 possible authenticators.'......

Answer (score 1):

You need to change MAIL_PORT to 587 and set encryption to tls   following is the example

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=host53.registrar-servers.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=no-reply@someemail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` to `MAIL_DRIVER=mail`

Answer (score 0):

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
PORT = 25
```

will work